# ActionScript 3 same symbol different instance name. Classes

Tags: actionscript-3

So I got a symbol named ball and it is connected to a class named Ball. I've put two balls in my game(not through the code) and used as instance names ball1,ball2.

The problem is I can't refer to their instance name because the code is in a class and not the frames.I can get the ball moving the same way.But I can't get them move differently by using their instance name.Unless I create another class/symbol for the second ball which is a waste because balls look the same and only 1-2 line of code will change in each class.

So how will I make it work without using different symbol/class?Can I refer to their instance name in order to get them moving differently although they are the same symbol/class?

this is the code that doesn't work:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Ball extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Ball():void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        }

        private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            ball1.x +=  2; //ball1 would fly right
                    ball2.y +=  2; // while ball2 would fly down but it doesn't work

        }
    }
}
```

this is the code that works and moves both ball the same way.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Ball extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Ball():void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        }

        private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            this.x +=  2; 
            this.y +=  2; 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use of classes extending objects for coding is called OOP in ActionScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MovieClip(root).ball1` and `MovieClip(root).ball2` to get things as if you got them from the timeline.  Right now, `this` refers to the class, so it wouldn't work by just referring them to their instance names.